# Avoid `{{- ... }}` Trim Extra Leading Whitespace in text/template of Golang?

Tags: go, templates, markdown, newline, go-templates

I attempt to render markdown list with `text/template` package of Go, and need to omit list items if the value is empty.

For example:

Full list rendering result:

```
# Debug Template 1

- Item A: Apple
- Item B: Bosch
- Item C: Cocola
- Item D: Delta
- Item E: Ellie
```

Expected result when B and D is empty:

```
# Debug Template 1

- Item A: Apple
- Item C: Cocola
- Item E: Ellie
```

So based on my full template:

```
# Debug Template 1

- Item A: {{ .ItemA }}
- Item B: {{ .ItemB }}
- Item C: {{ .ItemC }}
- Item D: {{ .ItemD }}
- Item E: {{ .ItemE }}
```

I tried to use `{{- ...}}` syntax to avoid newline, but it trimmed too much, and the newlines before the `{{- if ...}}` is also trimmed.

i.e. for the template (intentionally two newlines to demo this):

```
# Debug Template 2


{{- if .ItemA }}- Item A: {{ .ItemA }}
{{ end }}
{{- if .ItemB }}- Item B: {{ .ItemB }}
{{ end }}
{{- if .ItemC }}- Item C: {{ .ItemC }}
{{ end }}
{{- if .ItemD }}- Item D: {{ .ItemD }}
{{ end }}
{{- if .ItemE }}- Item E: {{ .ItemE }}
{{ end }}
```

Result:

```
# Debug Template 2- Item A: Apple
- Item B: Bosch
- Item C: Cocola
- Item D: Delta
- Item E: Ellie
```

Here's the code snippet:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func DemoRenderIssue() error {
    data := struct {
        ItemA string
        ItemB string
        ItemC string
        ItemD string
        ItemE string
    }{
        ItemA: "Apple",
        // ItemB: "Bosch",
        ItemC: "Cocola",
        // ItemD: "Delta",
        ItemE: "Ellie",
    }
    tmplStr := `
# Debug Template 1

- Item A: {{ .ItemA }}
- Item B: {{ .ItemB }}
- Item C: {{ .ItemC }}
- Item D: {{ .ItemD }}
- Item E: {{ .ItemE }}

# Debug Template 2


{{- if .ItemA }}- Item A: {{ .ItemA }}
{{ end }}
{{- if .ItemB }}- Item B: {{ .ItemB }}
{{ end }}
{{- if .ItemC }}- Item C: {{ .ItemC }}
{{ end }}
{{- if .ItemD }}- Item D: {{ .ItemD }}
{{ end }}
{{- if .ItemE }}- Item E: {{ .ItemE }}
{{ end }}
`
    tmpl, err := template.New("demo").Parse(tmplStr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, &data)
}
```

Can you please tell me how to fix the template or other skills to get the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure to keep the first newline:

```
# Debug Template 2

{{ if .ItemA }}- Item A: {{ .ItemA }}
{{ end }}
...
```

As the documentation states, `{{-` will clear all preceding whitespaces. In your case, using `{{- if .ItemA...` will clear all whitespaces up to the end of the string `Template 2` (newline is a whitespace). Simply keeping the first item in the list as `{{if .ItemA}}` preserves all whitespaces up to that point.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Can you please explain why it trim extra newlines if not keep the 1st newline?

Comment: I added more explanation to the answer